# Extracting/Filtering of string data based on z Coordinate

Tags: qgis, elevation, filter, extract

I have been supplied with a complex 3D file of a historic mine in .dxf format. The plan is made up of a series "slices", each slice captured at a specific elevation. I have successfully imported the .dxf file and saved it to a shape file. The Z co-ord has been confirmed to be part of the data. I am now attempting to extract/filter the string (note, fairly important it must be the string information, not points) for each mined elevation (i.e re-create the initial level plans) within QGIS. Logically this should be possible as all the relevant information is contained within the shape file, namely the z co-ordinate. Unfortunately nothing I have tried seems to work.

Would this be possible within a QGIS environment

Comment: Could you write, what you have tried and could you maybe attach a screenshot. For me at least it isn't straight forward, what you issue is here. Also: what do you mean with string-data: polygone-LINES, or text within the attribute table of the type string/text?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. As you have probably guessed, I'm pretty much a low end user of QGIS.

1) I imported .dxf and saved as a Line String shape file. Original .dxf is line data, not polygons.
2) initially attempted an "Extract by Z value" result attached "first Z" field being added but lost all other information.
3) I am able to extract vertices and export into a .csv file with Geometry set to XYZ. The resultant thousands of points, although accurate are not useful.

More than happy to send screenshots and .dxf file; not sure how to get them to you.

Comment: I have to offer my apologies, the "extract Z value" function had worked perfectly, however there was an error the layers CRS. Once corrected the shape file "re-appeared", complete with the "z_cordfirs" field in the attribute table. This has allowed me to extract the exact visual data I require, merely by filtering on the elevation. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: Nice to hear! You can *edit* your post and include imges (copy-pasting them). If you question is resolved one option is, to write a short answer by yourself & accept it. If someone else comes across this question it may help. OR you Edidt it and write into the question what the error was that found and how you resolved it.